# HAproxy single-arm loadbalancing

Tags: linux, networking, load-balancing, haproxy

I am trying to setup a loadbalancing lab for HAproxy in single-arm mode (when actual frontend IP and backend servers reside in same subnet, while actual clients are always remote). Another request is to make client source IPs visible to backend nodes. As we load-balance custom tcp-based app, it seems that option 'source 0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip' is a right choice here. Also, I have configured backends to have default-gateways pointing to HAproxy's IP address.

Although strange things happen once I enable this backend option: I see connection to frontend VIP was properly done and 3-way handshake formed. But when HAproxy server is trying to build a 2nd session to reach out to backend servers with spoofed IP of a client, I see exactly this happening:

1. Proxy is sending SYN with spoofed Client's IP address to one of the backends;
2. Backend is normally repsonds with SYN-ACK packet;
3. Proxy is NOT sending last ACK, just blindly sends SYN packets after timeout with same outcome;
4. On a proxy I see this connection is marked as SYN_SENT in netstat output, so it looks like proxy server doesn't accept actualy SYN-ACK packet for some reason.

Any commend would be appreciated.